# Problem with rolling window: ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am facing the following problem with Pandas and can't identify anything to be wrong.

```
churned_or_dormant_customers_by_month = jobs_by_customer_and_month.fillna(0).rolling(2, 2, axis='columns').apply(lambda window: 1 if not window[1] and window[0] else 0).sum(skipna=True)
```

The above gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 2059, in apply
    return super().apply(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1388, in apply
    return self._apply(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 586, in _apply
    result = np.apply_along_axis(calc, self.axis, values)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in apply_along_axis
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 379, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 576, in calc
    return func(x, start, end, min_periods)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1414, in apply_func
    values = Series(values, index=self.obj.index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 313, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 2.
```

Im sure this is not a bug but I am instead making a silly mistake using the rolling window function. I can't figure out what the mistake is though and I could swear that this worked with a previous version of Pandas. Which reminds me, the version I am runnning this code on is `1.1.0rc0`

Example data in pickle format is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dU6ePO2Dh6_rrwLfEAe-Nztdj-Su3C6k/view). and looks like this:

```
>>> jobs_by_customer_and_month
     2019-1  2019-2  2019-3
1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
2.0     2.0     2.5     2.1
```

Comment: The pickle file has this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189489/issues-working-with-pandas-dataframes-after-reinstallation

Answer (score 5):

Any version less than 0.23, value is always passed as ndarray . Option `raw` of `rolling apply` was implemented from version 0.23+. From version 0.23 to version < 1.0.0, `raw` is defaulted to `True`. However, it will produce a warning:

```
C:\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\ipython:3: FutureWarning: Currently, 'apply' passes
the values as ndarrays to the applied function. In the future, this will change
to passing it as Series objects. You need to specify 'raw=True' to keep the current 
behaviour, and you can pass 'raw=False' to silence this warning
```

You don't see any error or warning on your old pandas, so I guess your old version is < 0.23.

From version 1.0.0+, `rolling` officially default passes value as `series` (i.e. `raw=False`) to `apply`

***On your error, I guess it is a bug and it only appears when `rolling apply` along `axis = 1`*.**

I checked on version 0.24, this bug already exists. So, it probably appears along the implementation of passing value as `series` to the rolling object `apply`. However, This bug only appears when `rolling apply` along `columns` (in other words, `axis=1`).

On `rolling apply` along `axis = 1` and `series` passing as value, each series is a row in `df`. In your case, it has length = 3. I.e. it is `df.shape[1]`

```
df: 
     2019-1  2019-2  2019-3
1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
2.0     2.0     2.5     2.1

In [13]: df.loc[1.0].size
Out[13]: 3

In [14]: df.shape[1]
Out[14]: 3
```

Just look at your error trace-back above:

```
...
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1414, in apply_func
    values = Series(values, index=self.obj.index)
...
```

It tries to construct a series from `values` and use `self.obj.index` as index. `self` is the rolling object and `obj` is its attribute. Let's check what the value of `obj` is:

```
In [17]: (df.fillna(0)
    ...:    .rolling(window=3, axis='columns').__dict__
    ...:    )
Out[17]:
{'obj':      2019-1  2019-2  2019-3
 1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
 2.0     2.0     2.5     2.1,
 'on': None,
 'closed': None,
 'window': 3,
 'min_periods': None,
 'center': False,
 'win_type': None,
 'win_freq': None,
 'axis': 1,
 '_cache': {'_on': Index(['2019-1', '2019-2', '2019-3'], dtype='object'),
  'is_datetimelike': False},
 '_numba_func_cache': {}}
```

So, `self.obj` is the `df` itself. That means `self.obj.index` is `df.index` and its length is `2`

```
In [19]: df.index.size
Out[19]: 2
```

The construction of `series` checking length of data against length of `index` (inside file `series.py`)

```
...
if index is None:
    if not is_list_like(data):
        data = [data]
        index = ibase.default_index(len(data))
elif is_list_like(data):

    # a scalar numpy array is list-like but doesn't
    # have a proper length
    try:
        if len(index) != len(data):
            raise ValueError(
                f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
                f"index implies {len(index)}."
            )
    except TypeError:
        pass
...
```

As you see, length each row is `3` and length of `df.index` is 2, so it throws the ValueError.

It is a bug, so in the mean time, you need to specify your `rolling apply` with parameter `raw = True` to overcome this issue

Comment: Any idea if this bug is an open issue on https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?

Comment: @ScottBoston:  I am not familiar with pandas bugs report so I couldn't say for sure whether it was reported to the tracker. This bug seems not rare. Any one using rolling `apply` on `axis=1` would definitely get hit with it because in real dataset `df.shape[1]` is rarely equal `df.shape[0]`. Could you double check on the tracker and report it if it is not?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my issue was to use the parameter `raw=True` although I am confused as to why this should solve the issue. The documentation for [pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) states

> Must produce a single value from an ndarray input if raw=True or a
> single value from a Series if raw=False.

So it seems like the function returning a single value should work either way. This looks like there is a bug either in how `Rolling.apply` works or else in the documentation