# Issues working with pandas dataframes after reinstallation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

I have reinstalled Python and Anaconda and now I face the following issue.

After I have loaded a .pkl file to a dataframe and tried to 'take a look' at the file as follows:

```
df = pd.read_pickle("example.pkl")
df
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

Calling:

```
df.head()
```

delivers:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I have already tried to exceed the depth, but it led to a crush "Python has stopped working". I cannot remember changing the setting in the previous installation, though.

Does anyone of you know the possible solution?
Best regards!

Edit: I probably should add that the file has ca 50M rows (which again has not been an issue previously).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and temporarily avoid it by downgrading pandas from 1.1.0 to 1.0.3.

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.3
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same issue. Basically failed with pandas library installed with conda. After uninstalling it and re-installing with pip works fine!